# If I'm using a private struct, how do I declare it as an argument for the member functions listed above as public?

Tags: c++, struct

VS is not happy with the "Node*" argument for "makeEmptyHelper" because it does not 'see' the struct I guess.

```
public:
    void makeEmpty(); // make the tree empty so isEmpty returns true 
    void makeEmptyHelper(Node*);

private:
    struct Node {
        NodeData* data; // pointer to data object 
        Node* left; // left subtree pointer 
        Node* right; // right subtree pointer 
    };
    Node* root; // root of the tree
```

Comment: BTW - it's far more useful to include the actual compiler error, than to state that it 'is not happy'.

Comment: @BrettHale Yes I will keep that in mind for the future. Fortunately the error here was simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. I see two possible things you're trying to accomplish:

- Have `makeEmptyHelper` be accessible publicly but hide the contents of `struct Node`. In that case, you should either declare the fields of `struct Node` as private, or declare `struct Node`as public but only define its members in your implementation file.
- Have `makeEmptyHelper` be a helper function for another member function. In that case, make it private.

Comment: Since you were the first comment (by time) to point out the obvious flaw here I will accept your answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. You cannot have a function publicly available while it's argument is private. Either make the type of the argument public as well or make the method private.

Comment: Well I'm officially a moron. Thank you for helping me through this tiresome night.

Answer (score 0):

The Node struct is an argument of a public method of your class.

Therefore the Node struct is something that will be public outwards.

So the Node struct shall be public.